# Android Leakcanary leak using Flow while no leak using LiveData

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

If I use `Flow`, leak canary is showing a leak. Converting that flow to `LiveData` using `asLiveData()` there is no leak.

When my app is launched, in a `viewmodel` I'm doing the following:

```
itemsRepository
.getLatestItems() //Does a network request to get the latest items
.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
.onStart { .... }
.onEach { .... }
.catch { .... . }
.onCompletion { .... }
.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Leak Canary shows this:

```
→ xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.ItemsViewModel instance
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.
     ItemsViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback)
     Retaining 3.1 kB in 101 objects
     key = 66b151b2-fffb-4db9-91ec-716b456112ea
     watchDurationMillis = 11427
     retainedDurationMillis = 6427
```

Now, if I change the code to:

```
itemsRepository
.getLatestItems() //Does a network request to get the latest items
.asLiveData()
.observeForever { ... }
```

leak canary now does not say that I have a leak.

Any idea why using `Flow` as a leak and using `Livedata` no?
Since the flow is launched with `.launchIn(viewModelScope)` when the viewmodel scope is canceled, shouldn't the object be released?

Comment: You need to share the entire leaktrace, the cause of the leak can be identified by looking at the references pointing to the leaking object. Currently there's no enough info to help.